# Kafka acting as a Callback URL

Tags: apache-kafka, callback

Kafka on the base care works like a Publish & Subscribe (Pub/Sub) system, I have worked with Kafka in the past where I had specific Spring Boot application that acted as a Producer and another Spark application that was the consumer.

In both Producer and Consumer case the code was written in a way to interact with Kafka, as we had control over the application.

Now I wanted to understand if Kafka, can act as a Callback URL.

So the scenario is we have an external API (public API), which requests a Callback URL. So the idea was to check the feasibility of Kafka to act as a Callback URL instead of having a new service that is specifically built just to listen to the external API. So I could dedicate a specific topic to be acting as a Callback URL where all the requests sent by the client requests are captured and will further consume the topics using another application and process the messages.

**Requirements at Client side for the Callback URL**

```
Callback URL
The partner URL is called by our system to send notifications through HTTP POST requests. Make sure that your server can handle a HTTP HEAD request called to verify the validity of your URL.

NOTE
Your URL must:

start with https
be a valid URL, provided as a URL-encoded string. Please see w3schools URL encoding reference to learn more about URL encoding.
not be greater than 255 characters.
not contain an IP or 'localhost'. Only ports 80 and 443 are permitted.
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Kafka is not an HTTP service.

You will need to write your own HTTP server that wraps a KafkaProducer, and/or use tools like Kafka REST Proxy (but make sure the service doing the callback will send events in the expected format for that API).